# What is the Taylor expansion of a function from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2?$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, tensors

I would like to know what a second order expansion of a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ about $(0,0)$ is. I have seen that it should look something like
\begin{equation}
f(x,y) \approx f(0,0) + Df(0,0)\cdot(x,y) + \frac{1}{2} D^2 f(0,0) \cdot (x,y)^2.
\end{equation}
I was hoping someone could clarify what the last term in the sum is. What is the tensor $D^2 f(x,y)$ and how are the products in the last term defined?

Of course, correct me if the above equation is wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the Taylor expansion is expressed as follows:
$$
f(x^1,\dots,x^n) = f(0) + \sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}x^i + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}x^ix^j + R,
$$
where $R$ is some remainder term that goes to $0$ as $|x|^2\to 0$.

This can be rewritten by noting that the term
$$
\sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}x^i
$$
is the same as the action of the first derivative $D f(0)$, a $1\times n$ matrix, acting on the vector $x = (x^1,\dots,x^n)$. The term
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}x^ix^j
$$
can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{1}{2}x^T[D^2f(0)x],
$$
where $D^2f(0)$ is the Hessian matrix of $f$ evaluated at $0$. The Hessian is the $n\times n$ matrix of all mixed partial derivatives of second order. Here $x^T$ is the transpose of the vector $x$.

Concretely, if $n = 2$, then
$$
f(x,y) = f(0,0) + \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) & \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} + \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} x & y\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(0,0) & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}(0,0) \\ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}(0,0) & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(0,0) \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix} + R,
$$
where $R\to 0$ as $|(x,y)|^2\to 0$.

Comment: As an addendum, note that the "correct" array of numbers for the coordinate form of $D^2 f$ has two horizontal dimensions (appearing as a partitioned $4 \times 1$ matrix); the Hessian transposes one of those dimensions so that it can be written as a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to understand this is to do away with tensors by reducing to the single variable case: writing

$$ g_\vec{v}(t) = f(t \vec{v}) $$

several different forms for its Taylor polynomial are:

$$\begin{align}
g_\vec{v}(0) + t g'_\vec{v}(0) + \frac{t^2}{2} g''_{\vec{v}}(0) 
&= f(\vec{0}) + \nabla_\vec{v} f(\vec{0}) t + \frac{1}{2} \nabla_\vec{v}  \nabla_\vec{v} f(\vec{0}) t^2 
\\&= f(\vec{0}) + \nabla_\vec{tv} f(\vec{0}) + \frac{1}{2} \nabla_\vec{tv}  \nabla_\vec{tv} f(\vec{0}) 
\\&= f(\vec{0}) + (t\vec{v} \cdot \nabla) f(\vec{0}) + \frac{1}{2} (t\vec{v} \cdot \nabla)(t\vec{v} \cdot \nabla) f(\vec{0}) + \ldots 
\end{align}$$

Note I am using the full linear version of the directional derivative that satisfies $\nabla_{t \vec{v}} = t \nabla_\vec{v}$ and $\nabla_{\vec{v} + \vec{w}} = \nabla_\vec{v} + \nabla_{\vec{w}}$.

Tensors come into play because if $f$ is continuously twice differentiable, $\nabla_\vec{v} \nabla_\vec{w}$ is a bilinear form in $(\vec{v}, \vec{w})$. This bilinear form is what $D^2 f$ means. Thus, we have two more forms:

$$\begin{align}
\ldots 
&= f(\vec{0}) + Df(\vec{0})\cdot(t \vec{v}) + \frac{1}{2} D^2 f(\vec{0}) \cdot (t\vec{v}, \ t\vec{v} )
\\ &= f(\vec{0}) + Df(\vec{0})\cdot(t \vec{v}) + \frac{1}{2} D^2 f(\vec{0}) \cdot (t\vec{v} \otimes t\vec{v} )
\end{align}$$

where in both cases I've used $\cdot$ to mean "evaluate the (bi)linear form on the left at the (bi)vector(s) on the right".